# Postgres Dynamic COPY Statement

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to run a query that does a `foreach` of each element of an array, and then copies this to a directory with a custom named file.  Here's the code I have presently:

```
DO
$do$
declare
    x varchar;
    y varchar;
    arr varchar[] := array['item1','item2'];
begin
    foreach x in array arr
    loop
        y := concat('C:\Outputs\output_' , x , '.csv');
        copy (select * from pdtable where pdtable.area = x) to y With CSV;
    end loop;
end
$do$
```

However this encounters an error in the copy statment at the `to y` statement.  Is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: `EXECUTE format(...)`. Search for "postgres dynamic sql copy".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html

```
DO
$do$
declare
    x varchar;
    y varchar;
    arr varchar[] := array['item1','item2'];
begin
    foreach x in array arr
    loop
        y := concat('C:\Outputs\output_' , x , '.csv');
        execute format('copy (select * from pdtable where pdtable.area = %L) to %L With CSV',x,y);
    end loop;
end
$do$
```